# Dismissing modal view controller stack

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

Given the following view controller layout.

[image: View Controller Layout]

We build a stack of modal view controllers by first presenting `B` on `A` and then presenting `C` on `B`. According to the [Apple documentation on `dismiss(animated:completion:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:), calling it on `A` should actually dismiss the topmost view controller (`C` in this case) in an animated fashion and all intermediate view controllers without animation. What happens though is that `C` gets dismissed without animation and `B` is dismissed in an animated fashion.

I put up an [Xcode project on GitHub](https://github.com/mAu888/view-controllers-dismissal) that replicates that behaviour. Am I missing something or am I misunderstanding the documentation here?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I just ran into it and am pretty frustrated.  It seems as if this behavior has been around for several versions of iOS and is still present in iOS 10.  This goes directly against the documented behavior (and common sense) that you would animate the TOP most view controller and not the middle ones.

Comment: No I am still facing the issue. Maybe it's time to file a radar ...

Comment: Just found one... it was duplicated and then closed due to inactivity.  Also found a test project that quickly demonstrates the issue.  Apple thought they resolved it in 8.3 but the user never updated so they closed the bug... but it was still present and still is today.

Comment: I just submitted a bug report #28713792 to Apple.  I included the test project that someone else was nice enough to create so hopefully it is easily understood.

Comment: Will dupe that. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 7):

After poking around the web and trying out various 'solutions' it is clear this is an actual bug within iOS.  It has been present since iOS 8... and is still present in iOS 10.  It was originally reported in iOS 8, but the solution was never validated and Apple automatically closed the radar due to inactivity.

I have filed a new radar as this is in direct contradiction to the documentation for `dismissViewController`

> If you present several view controllers in succession, thus building a
>   stack of presented view controllers, calling this method(means
>   -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion]) on a view controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view
>   controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack.
>   When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated
>   fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the
>   stack.

Clear visualization of the issue, both expected and actual results.  Credit to [Boris Survorov](https://github.com/bsuvorov) for the test project and visualizations.

[image: Expected Results][image: Actual Results iOS 8+]

Comment: As an update, this has been slotted for resolution in iOS 11.x but has still not been fixed.

Comment: Just downloaded and ran the test project on iOS 12.  Nope, still broken.

Comment: Annnnnd still broken on iOS 13

Comment: I heard from some folks internal to Apple... if it isn't a regression bug, it isn't handled.  Stinks, but explains why this has sat unfixed for so many years.

Answer (score 5):

I've experienced the same issue and here is what I've found to be a viable workaround. When you need to dismiss the whole stack, execute this code in A:

```
viewControllerB.view.isHidden = true
viewControllerC.dismiss(animated: true) // or viewControllerB.dismiss(animated:true) - it should produce the same result: dismiss viewControllerC
dismiss(animated: false) // dismisses viewControllerB
```

This should result with the expected behavior.

Comment: @stanić Good call... it gets a little cumbersome if you have quite a few VCs stacked... but does get the job done.

Comment: @stanić does this work for you in iOS 10? I get a black screen behind the topmost controller while the animation is in progress.

Comment: @MikeBernardo Yes, it works on iOS 10 and iOS 11 for me. It's hard to tell what might be the issue with your case without more details. I suggest opening a separate question.

Comment: @SrđanStanić Thanks, I will open a new question. In the meantime I'd be curious if anyone can reproduce with this sample: https://github.com/mikebernardo2000/ModalDismissTest

Comment: OK, I got this to work. The missing piece is that you need to set the modalPresentationStyle on viewControllerB to "custom". Without doing that, you get a black screen like I mentioned above.

Comment: @MikeBernardo I'm glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that your segue from A to B is modal as well? In that case the `dismiss` function called from A wants to dismiss the view, which is immediately on top of A, which is B. C just gets hidden in order to show you the animated hiding of B. In that sense you cannot stack views via modal segues and dismiss the top one with the `dismiss` function as you described if you go that far back. The `dismiss` would work as intended if called from B to dismiss C though.

Comment: Although that could be under stable, that is not what the documentation spells out as the expected behavior.

Comment: @MobileVet Thanks! I didn't know that this was specified in the documentation. I also saw that you have submitted a bug report to Apple. Let's see what happens. Truth be told, I'd like that stack to work as well because it can be a pretty useful thing to have.