# Dismiss a presented view controller that has been presented by a presented view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am presenting a view controller with a presented view controller.

```
    let viewController = self.getResponseViewController(r: r)

    if let presented = self.presentedViewController {

        presented.present(viewController, animated: true)

    } else {

        self.present(viewController, animated: true)
    }
```

In the top level view controller, I have the following code...

```
presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)
```

This works ok apart from the fact that the top level view controller immediately disappears and it's the *first* presented view controller that is animated out.

If I merely do...

```
dismiss(animated: true)
```

... then only the top most view controller is dismissed, leaving the first presented controller still in place.

How can I have the top level view controller animate out to reveal the root view controller, whilst showing no sign of the first presented view controller?

Basically, I just need to be able to stack two levels deep.

Comment: This is a bug in UIKit. For possible workaround, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786974/dismissing-modal-view-controller-stack/41942466?noredirect=1#comment79476168_41942466

Answer (score 1):

So A presented B and B is now presenting C.
The easiest way to go to A, also as we don't want to see B exit, is to keep a reference to A and say dismiss or Pop to root on it from anywhere in C.
Or
Dismiss C and in completion handler dismiss B

Comment: 2nd solution would give a domino effect. How does one pop to root?

Comment: Yes, for 2 however try having the animated property as false and for popping to root we could use poptorootviewcontroller -
 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621855-poptorootviewcontroller

Comment: But that's for navigation controller, not presented view controllers.